# Value of async function can't be used

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, asyncstorage

I saved token into asyncstorage to be retrieved for authentication, but the problem is whenever i get the value, i log it into the console and it works but it doesn't send token to header, i have tried several method but all logic seems abortive. kindly help with your experience, or am I using the run asyncstorage?

```
export const editProfile = (userData) => {

  const storageGet = async () => {
    try {
         const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
         console.log("data", result);
         console.warn("data", result);
        return result;
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
  }

  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const userId = getState().auth._id
      axios.put(`${url}/users/${userId}`, userData,
      (async () => {                            // block of code to set auth token to header
        try{
          const x = await storageGet()
          console.log("nowToken", x)            // it returns the token into the console
          setHeaders(x)                         // but didn't set the token in the header
        }catch(err) {
          console.log(err.response)
        }
      })()
      //  setHeaders(token)
       )
          .then(response => {
            dispatch({
              type: "EDIT_PROFILE_SUCCESS",
              username: response.data.username,
              email: response.data.email,
              name: response.data.name,
              phoneNumber: response.data.phoneNumber,
              biography: response.data.biography,
              gender: response.data.gender,
              address: response.data.address,
              message: response.data.message,
              success: response.data.success
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response)
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: *"but didn't set the token in the header"* - Where/how do you observe that?  What is `setHeaders` and how are you confirming that it doesn't do what you expect?  If you've confirmed that the line **before** `setHeaders` works as expected but whatever happens **within** `setHeaders` is failing then what is the relevance of all of the code shown vs. just that one function?

Comment: Yes, I have copied the token generated into a variable and I set the variable into the setHeaders function and it works as expected, but what I noticed is that even if I set the variable into the setHeaders function within the async block, it won't work but if I set the variable into the setHeaders function outside the async block, it will work as expected.

Comment: What variable?  Where is `setHeaders` defined and where do you in any way observe the result of calling it?  Don't just describe what you *believe* the code you're not showing us is doing, update the code to a [mcve] which demonstrates what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the axios doc, the api is `axios.put(url[, data[, config]])`

your 3rd parameter (representing the config) is a function that isn't returning anything. Replace it with a function that returns the config object you want. e.g. ()=>{'authorization': await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")}

That should do the trick.

This may be more readable.

```
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")
const config = {headers: {'authorization':`bearer ${token}`}}
axios.put(`${url}/users/${userId}`, userData, config)
```

**edit** snippet was missing 'headers' key.

Comment: Dave... Thanks bro, you just save my life.

Comment: @NOTCHTRENDMEDIA great news. Please accept the answer.